# ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript: Feature Layer renderer not rendering UniqueValueInfos

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

My renderer for my featureLayer ([My feature layer](https://services3.arcgis.com/0OPQIK59PJJqLK0A/arcgis/rest/services/other_climate_2007_koppen_geiger/FeatureServer/0)) only renders the Legend but does not draw out any features on the map. It seems as though my uniqueValueGroups are working but uniqueValueInfos does nothing.

It may be because my `"field1" : "climate"` is not recognized and cannot be matched to any value within uniqueValueInfos. This may be the issue because adding        `"defaultSymbol" : {"type" : "simple-fill"},` to my unique-values renderer will render the features all in one color.

Heres the github link to my Renderer: [renderer](https://github.com/JaylenLuc/The_Biomes_Atlas/blob/main/atlas_main/pages/api/uniquevalueinforenderer.json)

Here are my fields for the featureLayer:

```
[
    {
        "fieldName": "FID",
        "isEditable": false,
        "label": "FID",
        "visible": false
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "climate",
        "isEditable": true,
        "label": "climate",
        "visible": true
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "identity_",
        "isEditable": true,
        "label": "identity",
        "visible": true
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "Shape__Area",
        "format": {
            "digitSeparator": true,
            "places": 2
        },
        "isEditable": false,
        "label": "Shape__Area",
        "visible": false
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "Shape__Length",
        "format": {
            "digitSeparator": true,
            "places": 2
        },
        "isEditable": false,
        "label": "Shape__Length",
        "visible": false
    }
]
```

I am using ArcGIS 4.28.10. Perhaps I should drop versions?

Here is the map when running. There are no features drawn. This is NOT what I want:
[image: Here is the map when running. There are no features drawn. This is NOT what I want]

This is what I want, with the features rendered:
[image]

What is interesting is that if I put the uniqueValueInfos after the uniqueValueGroups, the Legend will not render, it seems like it overwrites the UniquevalueGroups.

What I am guessing is that it does not recognize any fields associated with each feature for some reason. But when I put this featureLayer into arcgis Online, it clearly recognizes it has a field named "climate" and finds all the values of "climate" and renders them with a different color.

I flipped the ordered of the uniqueValueInfos and uniqueValueGroups which ended up not rendering the Legend if uniqueValueGroups went before uniqueValueInfos. I changed the Field name to identity (another field) and attempted to rendered one of the uniqueValueInfos by changing its value to its identity value which also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

"field1" : "climate"  in the renderer JSON should be changed to "field" : "climate" in the renderer. Getting rid of uniqueValueGroups entirely seemed to allow the uniqueValueInfos to be rendered properly.